# Trimming end of column in Power Query

Tags: powerquery, m

Hi I'm trying to trim the end of all contents in my column via power query but cant get my syntax correct.

The code I'm using is

> = Table.TransformColumns(#"Renamed Columns",Text.Start([Page path level 1],Text.Length([Page path level 1])-1))

The column I'm trying to do this to is called
'Page path level 1' and contents are
| /Account/ | /Retrieve/ | /Hello/

Comment: What's the contents you ultimately expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to remove the last character? Using your functions,

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Page path level 1", each Text.Start(_,Text.Length(_)-1)}})
```